# NLTK tree data structure, finding a node, it's parent or children

Tags: python, tree, nltk, parse-tree

I am using nltk's Tree data structure to work with parsetree strings.

```
from nltk.tree import Tree
parsed = Tree('(ROOT (S (NP (PRP It)) (VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (RB so) (JJ nice))) (. .)))')
```

The data structure, however, seems to be limited.
Is it possible to get a node by it's string value and then navigate to top or bottom?

For example suppose you want to get the node with string value *'nice'* and then see what's its parent, children, etc. Is it achievable via nltk's Tree?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407880/extracting-specific-leaf-value-from-nltk-tree-structure-with-python?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For NLTK 3.0, you want to use the ParentedTree subclass.

http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.ParentedTree

Using the sample tree you've given, create a ParentedTree and search for the node you want:

```
from nltk.tree import ParentedTree
ptree = ParentedTree.fromstring('(ROOT (S (NP (PRP It)) \
        (VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (RB so) (JJ nice))) (. .)))')

leaf_values = ptree.leaves()

if 'nice' in leaf_values:
    leaf_index = leaf_values.index('nice')
    tree_location = ptree.leaf_treeposition(leaf_index)
    print tree_location
    print ptree[tree_location]
```

You can iterate through the tree directly to get the child subtrees.  The parent() method is used to find the parent tree for the given subtree.

Here's an example using a deeper tree for child and parent:

```
from nltk.tree import ParentedTree
ptree = ParentedTree.fromstring('(ROOT (S (NP (JJ Congressional) \
    (NNS representatives)) (VP (VBP are) (VP (VBN motivated) \
    (PP (IN by) (NP (NP (ADJ shiny) (NNS money))))))) (. .))')

def traverse(t):
    try:
        t.label()
    except AttributeError:
        return
    else:

        if t.height() == 2:   #child nodes
            print t.parent()
            return

        for child in t:
            traverse(child)

traverse(ptree)
```

Comment: In addition: A "tree position" is a tuple, describing a path down the tree. So if you have the path to a node, e.g., `tree_location` as in the answer, its parent will be at `tree_location[:-1]`. This works for both `Tree` and `ParentedTree`.