# NLTK separately extract leaves and non-leaf nodes

Tags: python, tree, nlp, nltk, nodes

I'm working with the [Standford Sentiment Treebank](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/) dataset and I'm attempting to extract the leaves and the nodes. The data is given follows

```
(3 (2 (2 The) (2 Rock)) (4 (3 (2 is) (4 (2 destined) (2 (2 (2 (2 (2 to) (2 (2 be) (2 (2 the) (2 (2 21st) (2 (2 (2 Century) (2 's)) (2 (3 new) (2 (2 ``) (2 Conan)))))))) (2 '')) (2 and)) (3 (2 that) (3 (2 he) (3 (2 's) (3 (2 going) (3 (2 to) (4 (3 (2 make) (3 (3 (2 a) (3 splash)) (2 (2 even) (3 greater)))) (2 (2 than) (2 (2 (2 (2 (1 (2 Arnold) (2 Schwarzenegger)) (2 ,)) (2 (2 Jean-Claud) (2 (2 Van) (2 Damme)))) (2 or)) (2 (2 Steven) (2 Segal))))))))))))) (2 .)))
```

what I would like so for something as follows:

i) The leaves with the label (uni-gram):

```
[(2 The), (2 Rock), (2 is), (2 destined),...]
```

ii) uper nodes with the labels (bi-gram):

```
[(2 (2 the) (2 Rock)), (2 (2 ``) (2 Conan)), (2 (2 Century) (2 's)),..]
```

until I get to the root of the tree.

I've attempted to use regex to accomplish this but it fails to output correctly.

The code I have (for the uni-gram):

```
import re
import nltk

location = '.../NLP/Standford_Sentiment_Tree_Data_Set/' +\
           'trainDevTestTrees_PTB/trees/train.txt'
text = open(location, 'r')

test = text.readlines()[0]
text.close()

uni_regex = re.compile(r'(\([0-4] \w+\))')
temp01 = uni_regex.findall(test)

# bi-gram
bi_regex = re.compile(r'(\([0-4] \([0-4] \w+\) \([0-4] \w+\)\))')
temp02 = bi_regex.findall(test)
```

The above code outputs:

```
['(2 The)', '(2 Rock)', '(2 is)', '(2 destined)', '(2 to)', '(2 be)', '(2 the)', '(2 21st)', '(2 Century)', '(3 new)',...]
```

and fails to capture ``` (2 ``) ```, `(2 '')` and extracts `(2 Jean)` instead of `(2 Jean-Claude)`

The output fails to capture ``` (2 (2``) (2 Conan)) ```

Is there a way to get the result that I want using `nltk` or some configuration of `regex` that will not miss any tokens?

I've had a look and attempted to modify the solution provided in [NLTK tree data structure, finding a node, it's parent or children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815002/nltk-tree-data-structure-finding-a-node-its-parent-or-children) but that question seems to deal with finding a specific word in a leave and the displaying the tree structure, whereas I require the indented solution to resemble the above n-grams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't  waste your time with regexps, this is what tree classes are for. Use the nltk's `Tree` class like this:

```
mytree = "(3 (2 (2 The) (2 Rock)) (4 (3 (2 is) (4 (2 destined) (2 (2 (2 (2 (2 to) (2 (2 be) (2 (2 the) (2 (2 21st) (2 (2 (2 Century) (2 's)) (2 (3 new) (2 (2 ``) (2 Conan)))))))) (2 '')) (2 and)) (3 (2 that) (3 (2 he) (3 (2 's) (3 (2 going) (3 (2 to) (4 (3 (2 make) (3 (3 (2 a) (3 splash)) (2 (2 even) (3 greater)))) (2 (2 than) (2 (2 (2 (2 (1 (2 Arnold) (2 Schwarzenegger)) (2 ,)) (2 (2 Jean-Claud) (2 (2 Van) (2 Damme)))) (2 or)) (2 (2 Steven) (2 Segal))))))))))))) (2 .)))"

>>> t = nltk.Tree.fromstring(mytree)
>>> print(t)
(3
  (2 (2 The) (2 Rock))
  (4
    (3
      (2 is)
      (4
        (2 destined)
        (2
          ...
```

You can then extract and count the leaves, and request the corresponding "treepositions" (the path to each leaf, in the form of a list):

```
>>> leafpos = [ t.leaf_treeposition(n) for n, x in enumerate(t.leaves()) ]
>>> print(leafpos[0:3])
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Finally, you can walk up the treepositions to get the units you want: the subtree dominated by the node immediately above each leaf, two steps above each leaf, etc:

```
>>> level1_subtrees = [ t[path[:-1]] for path in leafpos ]
>>> for x in level1_subtrees:
...     print(x, end = " ")
(2 The) (2 Rock) (2 is) (2 destined) (2 to) (2 be) (2 the) ...

>>> level2_subtrees = [ t[path[:-2]] for path in leafpos ]
```

Note, however, that higher-level subtrees don't look like you imagine. If you go up two levels from leaf 3 (`destined`), for example, you won't get a "bigram". You'll be at the node  labeled `4`, which dominates most of the rest of the sentence. Perhaps you're actually interested in enumerating all subtrees? In that case, just iterate over `t.subtrees()`.

If that's not what you want, take a look at the `Tree` API and pick out another way to select the parts you need.